# How to import Cocos2d-x in codeblocks ide?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

Is it possible to import cocos2d-x in codeblocks just as in xcode ?? How can I do that ?

I use ubuntu. It is not possible to use xcode in ubuntu. Cocos2dx is in c++. How can I use codeblocks for game development with cocos2dx??

Thanks

Comment: If you're unable to find aby good tutorials, I suggest you to look what options xcode uses to compile your project, and then manually type these options into codeblocks project settings.

Answer (score 1):

I got answer for my own question.

refer to this link    http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/can-someone-tell-me-how-to-setup-cocos2d-x-on-code-blocks/10144/2

I follow these steps.

1) Create cbp file with the command 
        cmake ../ -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles"

2) Open it in Codeblocks

This solved  my problem.